# Como inserir âncoras para minha página?

Tags: html, html5

Tenho uma pagina chamada de `noticias.html` com várias notícias divididas em vários artigos, mas só falta os *links* dessa parte que ta escrita "CONTINUE LENDO..." que eu gostaria de fazer com que ao clicar nessa parte a notícia abrisse toda com o restante  das informações

Meu código é esse:

```css
section {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #dedede;
}

article {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: yellow;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

a {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 7px;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: red;
  display: table;
  position: relative;
  top: 150px;
}

h2 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <article>Notícia 01
    <a href="">continue lendo...</a>
  </article>

  <article>Notícia 02
    <a href="">continue lendo...</a>
  </article>

  <article>Notícia 03
    <a href="">continue lendo...</a>
  </article>

  <article>Notícia 04
    <a href="">continue lendo...</a>
  </article>

</section>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Quando você diz "a notícia abrisse toda", você quer dizer que deseja que esse contêiner expanda o seu tamanho, ou você quer que a notícia seja aberta em outra página?

Comment: acho que ela abrir em outra pagina seria melhor  ...

Comment: @GustavoSampaio gostaria de uma  ajuda  nessa parte .
eu vejo em muitos sites de notícias  mais  não sei  como e que funciona isso 
alguém me ajudem por favor

Comment: qual o padrão usado pelo os sites de notícias ?

Comment: tipo esse 
http://valemaisnoticias.com.br/category/mutuipe/  ?

Comment: `<a target="_blank" href="link_da_notícia.html">CONTINUE LENDO...</a>`

Comment: @Sam como eu faço para abrir a noticia em uma nova pagina mais com um tamanho que não ocupe 100% da pagina ?

Comment: @hugocsl  como eu faço para abrir a noticia em uma nova pagina mais com um tamanho que não ocupe 100% da pagina ?

Comment: @jonassouza isso seria uma "nova pergunta" e não seria possível te responder tudo em um comentário. Te sugiro abrir uma Nova Pergunta, ai vc coloca o código de como vc vai querer apresentar a noticia e só assim vai dar pra te ajudar de uma forma correta e que vai te atender 100%

Answer (score 1):

Se seu botão *CONTINUE LENDO...* for um elemento `<a>`, é só adicionar o atributo`href`, direcionando para a página da notícia em questão, conforme o que o @hugocsl falou. Já se for um elemento `<button>`, você pode adicionar o atributo `onclick`, para que quando o botão for clicado, a página da notícia em questão seja aberta, através da declaração exemplificada pelo @OtavioCapel, ou através do método `open`, também pertencente ao objeto `window`, da seguinte forma:

**Abre a notícia em outra guia**

```
window.open('link_da_noticia');
```

ou

**Abre a notícia na mesma guia**

```
window.open('link_da_noticia', '_self');
```

Isso tudo considerando que você quer abrir a notícia em uma outra página.

> Qual o padrão usado pelos sites de notícias?

Contando o exemplo que você forneceu, com mais outros dois exemplos que procurei, acho que o padrão deles é abrir a notícia em outra página, porém na mesma guia.